# C# Notmapped field not "Set" when value is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

We have a notmapped conversion field with a kendo control bound to it. When we delete all entries from the control, it posts a null to the controller.
The created model is not running the setter for that field, according to the breakpoints I set in it.

Here's the two fields in question:

```
        [NotMapped]
    [Display(Name="Execute Time(s)")]
    [DCRequired]
    public IList<int> ExecuteTimes {
        get 
        {
            return ExecuteHourUTC?.Split(',').Select(s => GetUtcHour(s)).ToList();
        } 
        
        set 
        {
            if (value != null)
            {   
                // Special code here to ensure the times are numerically in order by local time
                // and saved that way for viewing on next load or in the grid.
                var values = value.ToList()                                                                                 // convert to List to be sortable/linqable
                    .OrderBy(x => x)                                                                                        // sort numerically so they are stored in chronological order
                    .Select(x => new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.Year, DateTime.UtcNow.Month, DateTime.UtcNow.Day, x, 0, 0))   // use the integer value to create a DateTime
                    .Select(d => Core.DateHelper.ToUTC(d, UserTimeZone).Hour);                                              // convert the generated DateTime into a UTC DateTime and return the Hour value
                ExecuteHourUTC = string.Join(",", values);                                                                  // join these Hour (int) values as a CSV
            }
        }
    }


        [Display(Name="Execute Times")]
    public string ExecuteHourUTC { get; set; }
```

execute hour utc is bound to the database.
Note:  I fixed the problem this was causing (it was leaving the old values in the db field) by bind excluding the db field from the post.  I just want to know what the actual reason I'm having this issue is.

I also tried changing the datatype to iList<int?>.  That didn't help.